# LLC capital equipment against day job income

Tags: united-states, income-tax, limited-liability-company, capital-loss

My wife and I have started an LLC. the LLC is run our of our house, it is a machine shop. We file our taxes joint-married. She is 51% owner I am 49% owner.

I work a day job (for now).

We have purchased equipment for the LLC, lets say $20k worth. Some is consumables (cutters, grinding disks, band saw blades) some is actual equipment. No single piece cost me more than about $3,000.

Lets say I make $100k at my day job. 
From what I have read, the capital equipment will be depreciated? or is it a low enough dollar amount to be a straight write off?

The lifetime of the consumables seems to put those items into a different deduction category...operating expense?
We have very little organizational expenses, but I am guessing Phone bill (under the business name), website count?

To date we have done about $1,000 in business.

my questions:

1. how do I know if the equipment (all used) gets depreciated/amortized or just
   written off?
2. if it is to be depreciated/amortized: how do I determine the schedule for an older machine which is used?
3. as a pass through, does all of the business expenses (which is equipment and which will out weigh profits this year) get deducted
   off our personal income tax?
4. I have read that the my 'day job' income will determine how much benefit I can get from the LLC expenses/loss, where do I find this information?

Thank you ahead of time, and if there is a good link for this sort of information, please point me that direction. I did some searches but didn't find much about how LLC loses affect, or are related to, day job income.

Comment: So please correct me if I have incorrect information: 1. equipment with a life time of more than 1 year has to be depreciated, anything less than that can be a full write off...? still looking for property class, especially since its is all used

Comment: in the MACRS system it appears I can group assets of the same 'class' to be depreciated as a single asset, is this something I want to do if some equipment has longer life than others?